# Who sent the FB message?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

someone sent my wife a facebook message that was terrible, then they conveniently deleted that FB account.  Is there any way to find out who sent it??  At all??  I'm thinking we know the person.  Don't just want to block them. I'd like to know who sent it.

Comment: The following may be useful: [Report a conversation on Messenger](https://www.facebook.com/help/messenger-app/1165699260192280).